# Does Astro js need a backend framework like ExpressJS, Django, or Flask?

Tags: astrojs

I know that Astro js is like a server that can use multiple front-end frameworks such as React, but does astro.js need a back-end framework?

Answer (score 3):

No, you don't need a backend framework to run Astro. Basically, for simple projects you don't even have to choose a front-end framework as well, and just use built-in functionality, there is a lot to choose from.

From the [docs](https://docs.astro.build/en/concepts/why-astro/#fully-featured-but-flexible):

> Astro is an all-in-one web framework that comes with everything you need to build a website.
>
> Astro includes a component syntax, file-based routing, asset handling, a build process, bundling, optimizations, data-fetching, and more. You can build great websites without ever reaching outside of Astro’s core feature set.
>
> If you need more control, you can extend Astro with over 100+ integrations like React, Svelte, Vue, Tailwind CSS, MDX, image optimizations, and more. Connect your favorite CMS or deploy to your favorite host with just a single command.